# I wonder why I can't get ParseCrashReporting into my XCode project

Tags: ios, xcode

The error message is this:

```
Ld /Users/RMacMini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParseStarterProject-Swift-ckffbprwvtawqmhfaxjbyvhaipts/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ParseStarterProject-Swift.app/ParseStarterProject-Swift normal arm64
cd "/Users/RMacMini/Desktop/Mystery Date/parse-starter-project-1.10.0/ParseStarterProject-Swift"
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
export PATH="/Volumes/R TM/Apps from old MM HD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Volumes/R TM/Apps from old MM HD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Volumes/R\ TM/Apps\ from\ old\ MM\ HD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Volumes/R\ TM/Apps\ from\ old\ MM\ HD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk -L/Users/RMacMini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParseStarterProject-Swift-ckffbprwvtawqmhfaxjbyvhaipts/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Users/RMacMini/Desktop/Mystery\ Date/parse-starter-project-1.10.0/ParseStarterProject-Swift -F/Users/RMacMini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParseStarterProject-Swift-ckffbprwvtawqmhfaxjbyvhaipts/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/RMacMini/Desktop/Mystery\ Date/parse-starter-project-1.10.0/ParseStarterProject-Swift -filelist /Users/RMacMini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParseStarterProject-Swift-ckffbprwvtawqmhfaxjbyvhaipts/Build/Intermediates/ParseStarterProject-Swift.build/Debug-iphoneos/ParseStarterProject-Swift.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ParseStarterProject-Swift.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -L/Volumes/R\ TM/Apps\ from\ old\ MM\ HD/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/RMacMini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParseStarterProject-Swift-ckffbprwvtawqmhfaxjbyvhaipts/Build/Intermediates/ParseStarterProject-Swift.build/Debug-iphoneos/ParseStarterProject-Swift.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ParseStarterProject_Swift.swiftmodule -lsqlite3 -lstdc++.6.0.9 -lsqlite3 -lz -framework ParseUI -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework ParseFacebookUtils -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework Parse -framework Bolts -framework AdSupport -framework AssetsLibrary -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/RMacMini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParseStarterProject-Swift-ckffbprwvtawqmhfaxjbyvhaipts/Build/Intermediates/ParseStarterProject-Swift.build/Debug-iphoneos/ParseStarterProject-Swift.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ParseStarterProject-Swift_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/RMacMini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ParseStarterProject-Swift-ckffbprwvtawqmhfaxjbyvhaipts/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ParseStarterProject-Swift.app/ParseStarterProject-Swift

ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: You may follow the suggest that is being in the error message `-v` and see.

Comment: ld: entry point (_main) undefined. said the reason

Comment: Ok, how do you use -v?